# Workflow task edit form

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I want to add a new button to a workflow task edit form. I want to call this button "Incomplete". The purpose of this button is to mark an item as incomplete instead of rejecting it. If the task item is marked as "incomplete" then the user can get an e-mail to edit the form and resubmit it again to kick off a workflow. Where as rejecting it would just stop everything.

The button was added along with the approve, reject buttons under the task outcomes section. See below:

[image: screenshot]

This button works great. I can see it on the task edit form.

The issue is in the workflow. How do I know what button the user clicked when the task completes? The workflow only handles cases where you either approve or reject the task. See below:

[image: screenshot]

When the task completes I want to see if the user clicked "Incomplete" and if so set the WidgetApprovalStatus="Incomplete".

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you can do that this way:

On the task edit page in SPD you want to click on the **Change the behavior of a single task** link:

[image: Change behavior screenshot]

Then in the **When a Task Completes** section add a **If task outcome equals value** condition, select the first **value** argument and you'll see a dropdown, pick either **Number of Incompleted** or **Percentage of Incompleted** and enter **1** or **100** respectively into the second **value** argument:

[image: When task completes screenshot]

You can then set the value of your property to **incomplete**. Should do the trick...let me know if what I'm suggesting is unclear or you need more detail.

Comment: Thank you, Rob D'Oria. This is exactly what I was looking for.